# Android layout_gravity issue

Tags: android, layout, gravity

I am trying to use gravity as start(`android:layout_gravity="start"'`)
 in following code

but no luck as of yet.

**Here is the Layout :**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:scrollIndicators="none">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

        android:layout_width="90pt"
        android:layout_height="440dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material"
        android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false">


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why you set `pt` ?

Comment: to hide the drawer menu, so i can slide the menu to show it. i don't want it to be visible always

Comment: have you tried it with dp.

Answer (score 1):

Use Drawer Layout instead of Linear Layout. For Navigation view the parent layout should always be DrawerLayout.